# Permission group still display at the top level even after breaking inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a page with a list on it. When I go to the list settings and choose to set the permissions. I first cut the inheritance and then connect the list with a permission group called X that has the permission EDIT. But when I go to the sitepermissions where the Visitors, Owners and Member groups are displayed I see also the group X. Even thou I have cut the inheritance I still see group x at top level. How can I correct this?

Greetings, Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint groups are created at site level and not at the list level.

So what you can do is, give the least permission(read or anything you want to give) to group X on site level.

And then in list permissions give EDIT permissions to the same group.